# Determine, is module name already defined, without loading module

Tags: python

I want to allow user to make module file, if name isn't defined in Py3k already. (In it's portable installation). For ex, if user enters "ppp" i must check first, if module "ppp" exists in Py installation (it exists here!) and disallow this name. If he enters "my_name" i must allow it and if enters "ppp" or "json" I must disallow it.

Any way doing this check without doing "import" first? such import may take much memory. I only want to check if module name **can be imported**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`pkgutil`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules) module, something like this:

```
import pkgutil

def module_exists(m):
    for module_loader, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules():
        if name == m:
            return True
    return False
```